# Getting javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: - although consuming service has a CA certificate

Tags: java, spring-boot, https

In my app "A" I need to write a method that requests to the other service "B" through https protocol at a certain stand

Right now I have a following exception

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: 
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path 
to requested target
at reactor.core.Exceptions.propagate(Exceptions.java:393)
at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:97)
at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1680)
at ru.raiffeisen.bgt.initiative.service.impl.HomeServiceImpl.graphqlRequest(HomeServiceImpl.kt:306)
at ...
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid 
certification path to requested target
```

I made some research and everywhere is said that I need to download a certificate and put it on my JVM.
But if I do so, will it not work only on my local machine ?

How to resolve this issue ??

Comment: Get the server to use a CA-signed certificate and save yourself bother forever.

Comment: @user207421 Service B already has CA certificate. When I try to access through web browser, everything works. But it does not work through WebClient